# Either-or condition for equality constraints

Tags: optimization, constraints, binary-programming

Consider the following optimization problem
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\text{min} & \sum_{j\in J} c_jx_j \\
& \quad \sum_{j\in J} a_{1j}x_j \leq b_1 \\
& \quad \sum_{j\in J} a_{2j}x_j \leq b_2 \\
& \quad x_j \geq 0 \quad \forall j\in J
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
It is well known that, if we need to impose that just one of these two constraints must be satisfied, then we can use introduce a binary variable $y\in\{0,1\}$ and two upper bounds $M_1$ and $M_2$ so that
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\text{min} & \sum_{j\in J} c_jx_j \\
& \quad \sum_{j\in J} a_{1j}x_j \leq b_1 + M_1y\\
& \quad \sum_{j\in J} a_{2j}x_j \leq b_2 +M_2(1-y)\\
& \quad x_j \geq 0 \quad \forall j\in J
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Imagine that, in the initial problem, the constraints are equalities, that is to say,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\text{min} & \sum_{j\in J} c_jx_j \\
& \quad \sum_{j\in J} a_{1j}x_j = b_1 \\
& \quad \sum_{j\in J} a_{2j}x_j = b_2 \\
& \quad x_j \geq 0 \quad \forall j\in J
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
How can we impose that just one of these constraints holds with binary variables?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by reformulating each equality constraint as two inequality constraints:
\begin{align}
& \quad \sum_{j\in J} a_{1j}x_j \leq b_1 +M_1y \\
& \quad \sum_{j\in J} a_{1j}x_j \geq b_1 -M_1y \\
& \quad \sum_{j\in J} a_{2j}x_j \leq b_2 +M_2(1-y) \\
& \quad \sum_{j\in J} a_{2j}x_j \geq b_2 -M_2(1-y)
\end{align}